# How do I create an EJB 3.1 Project with eclipse kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, ejb, eclipse-kepler

I just wanna get into EJB, but i refuse to use this all-in-one program netbeans+glassfisch. My jboss 7.1 is already running and added as server. I tried to create an Enterprise Application Project but it won't let me create any beans, says "source folder is not a java project."

Maybe I need to install some updates? In Indigo there seems to be an option for creating an ejb-project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse Web Tools you forced to have separate project for Every Java EE artifact. You need first create Enterprise Application Project. Then use New EJB Project and select "Add project to an EAR". After that you should be able to create beans in EJB Project.